# moving circles in pygame

Tags: python, pygame, pygame-surface

I have a code that moves all the circles from a spirograph away from the center. This is how its supposed to look like: [image: this is how it is supposed to start out before it gets moved]

Then, I want to move the **all** of the circles, together, at once, away from the center: [image: this is what its supposed to look like after its been moved]

This is my current code:

```
import time
import pygame
import math
import sys

# setting colors
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
ORANGE = (255, 127, 0)
YELLOW = (255, 255, 0)
PURPLE = (160, 32, 240)
# setting what order the colors go in
listCircleColor = (RED, BLUE, GREEN, ORANGE, YELLOW, PURPLE, WHITE)
# how many circles per color
intGroup = 5
# the space between each circle
turnangle = 360 / 35
# width of screen
width = 600
# height of screen
height = 600
# radius of circles
radius = 100
# making the screen
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
# if the code is running, then continue
running = True
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

##.draw.circle(screen, BLUE, (0, 0), radius, width=2)
alpha = turnangle
circles = []
# draw
alpha = turnangle
for i in range(intGroup):
    for cl in listCircleColor:
        if alpha > 0 and alpha < 90:
            x = 300 + radius * math.cos(math.radians(alpha))
            y = 300 + radius * math.sin(math.radians(alpha))
            pygame.draw.circle(screen, cl, (x, y), radius, width=2)
            # second quarter of circles
        if alpha > 90 and alpha < 180:
            x = 300 - radius * math.cos(math.radians(180 - alpha))
            y = 300 + radius * math.sin(math.radians(180 - alpha))
            pygame.draw.circle(screen, cl, (x, y), radius, width=2)
            # third quarter of circles
        if alpha > 180 and alpha < 270:
            x = 300 - radius * math.cos(math.radians(alpha - 180))
            y = 300 - radius * math.sin(math.radians(alpha - 180))
            pygame.draw.circle(screen, cl, (x, y), radius, width=2)
            # last quarter of circles
        if alpha > 270 and alpha < 360:
            x = 300 + radius * math.cos(math.radians(360 - alpha))
            y = 300 - radius * math.sin(math.radians(360 - alpha))
            pygame.draw.circle(screen, cl, (x, y), radius, width=2)

        circles.append(([x, y], cl, alpha))
        alpha = alpha + turnangle
        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(10)
        #circle = [pygame.draw.circle(screen, cl, (300 + radius * math.cos(math.radians(alpha)), 300 + radius * math.sin(math.radians(alpha))), radius, width=2)]
        #circles = {'circles': circle.get_rect()}

# move"
trangleedge = radius
movetimes = 1
time.sleep(2)



# exit only when user clicks on exit button
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit()
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    while movetimes <= 100:
        trangleedge = trangleedge + 1
        for circle in circles:
            #x = circle[0][0]
            #y = circle[0][1]
            alpha = circle[2]
            cl = circle[1]

            if alpha > 0 and alpha < 90:
                x = 300 + trangleedge * math.cos(math.radians(alpha))
                y = 300 + trangleedge * math.sin(math.radians(alpha))
                #pygame.draw.circle(screen, cl, (x, y), radius, width=2)
                # second quarter of circles
            if alpha > 90 and alpha < 180:
                x = 300 - trangleedge * math.cos(math.radians(180 - alpha))
                y = 300 + trangleedge * math.sin(math.radians(180 - alpha))
                #pygame.draw.circle(screen, cl, (x, y), radius, width=2)
                # third quarter of circles
            if alpha > 180 and alpha < 270:
                x = 300 - trangleedge * math.cos(math.radians(alpha - 180))
                y = 300 - trangleedge * math.sin(math.radians(alpha - 180))
                #pygame.draw.circle(screen, cl, (x, y), radius, width=2)
                # last quarter of circles
            if alpha > 270 and alpha < 360:
                x = 300 + trangleedge * math.cos(math.radians(360 - alpha))
                y = 300 - trangleedge * math.sin(math.radians(360 - alpha))
                #pygame.draw.circle(screen, cl, (x, y), radius, width=2)

            circle[0][0] = x
            circle[0][1] = y
            screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
            for center, color, alpha in circles:
                pygame.draw.circle(screen, color, center, radius, 2)

            pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(60)
        movetimes += 1
```

this is the result:[image]

It creates basically 2 pictures and blits them together, but I don't want that. I want it to start out as a spirograph and then all the circles slowly move away from the center at once.

Edit: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ODIVY.jpg This is what the finished project is supposed to look like, but there is no "delay" when the circles move.What i mean is that the circles should be moving together, and not one by one like the code shown here.

Edit 2: I achieved what i wanted thanks to someone showing me their code. I then took their code as an example and made it what i described.  Now i just need to move the circles in groups of their color.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the distance from the center of each circle to the center of the window. Use [`pygame.math.Vector2`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html#pygame.math.Vector2). Coumpute the vector (`v`) from the center of the window to the center of the circle and scale it with [`scale_to_length`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html#pygame.math.Vector2.scale_to_length):

```py
window_center = pygame.math.Vector2(300, 300)
for circle in circles:
    circle_center = pygame.math.Vector2(circle[0])
    v = circle_center - window_center 
    v.scale_to_length(distance_from_center)
    new_circle_center = window_center + v
    circle[0][0] = round(new_circle_center.x)
    circle[0][1] = round(new_circle_center.y)
```

Change `distance_from_center` by time:

```py
direction = 1
distance_from_center = radius

while running:
    # [...]

    distance_from_center += direction
    if distance_from_center >= 200 or distance_from_center <= 100:
        direction *= -1
```

If you just want to move the circles outward, here's what you can do:

```py
distance_from_center = radius

while running:
    # [...]

    if distance_from_center < 200:
        distance_from_center += 1
```

---

Complete example:

[image]

```py
import pygame
import math

# setting colors
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
ORANGE = (255, 127, 0)
YELLOW = (255, 255, 0)
PURPLE = (160, 32, 240)
# setting what order the colors go in
listCircleColor = (RED, BLUE, GREEN, ORANGE, YELLOW, PURPLE, WHITE)
# how many circles per color
intGroup = 5
# the space between each circle
turnangle = 360 / 35
# width of screen
width = 600
# height of screen
height = 600
# radius of circles
radius = 100
# making the screen
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
# if the code is running, then continue
running = True

##.draw.circle(screen, BLUE, (0, 0), radius, width=2)
alpha = turnangle
circles = []
# draw
alpha = turnangle
for i in range(intGroup):
    for cl in listCircleColor:
        x = 300 + radius * math.cos(math.radians(alpha))
        y = 300 + radius * math.sin(math.radians(alpha))
        circles.append(([x, y], cl, alpha))
        alpha = alpha + turnangle

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
direction = 1
distance_from_center = radius

while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    window_center = pygame.math.Vector2(300, 300)
    for circle in circles:
        circle_center = pygame.math.Vector2(circle[0])
        v = circle_center - window_center 
        v.scale_to_length(distance_from_center)
        new_circle_center = window_center + v
        circle[0][0] = round(new_circle_center.x)
        circle[0][1] = round(new_circle_center.y)

    # move in and out
    distance_from_center += direction
    if distance_from_center >= 200 or distance_from_center <= 100:
        direction *= -1

    # only move out
    #if distance_from_center < 200:
    #    distance_from_center += 1

    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    for center, color, alpha in circles:
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, color, center, radius, 2)
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(40)

pygame.quit()
exit()
```